# Text field displays value but doesn't catch it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, entity-attribute-value

I am working on the project that needs to be updates with some functions. One is where i need to update EAV registration form and make choose option, where i have 2 radio buttons and text field. When I click on one of the radio buttons, it takes the value and places it in the input textbox. The problems starts when i try to save registration. This text field attributes are saved in database where one of them is "isRequired". I can't save form because textfield asks to type something in it, but there is already a value. When I disable "isRequired" it saves the form, but there is no value saved in database. When I type any symbol next to radio button value required field disappears and then I can save the value in database. That's why my question is why field can't catch the value. I will put some of the code in this question because I can't make test environment. Have only files on the server. Hope someone can answer or give some clues what to do. I have opinions that this problem might be cause by keypress events, angularjs, jquery or EAV model.

Image: [https://postimg.org/image/j8mgjia1d/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXhSk.png)

Creating fields:

```
backendComponents.directive('eavFormatted', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="form-group field_eav field_eav_{{ config.ID }} field_eav_{{ config.handle }}"><label class="control-label">{{ config.name }}</label><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var config = JSON.parse(attrs.config);
            scope.config = config;
            delete attrs.config;
            element.removeAttr('ng-transclude');
        }
    }
});

backendComponents.directive('eavField', function($compile, $timeout) {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope: true,
                replace: true,
                link: function(scope, element, attrs)

                if (html) {
                    var fieldName = 'eav_' + config.ID;
                    if (config.isRequired) {
                        html = html + '<div class="text-danger" ng-show="isSubmitted && eavform.' + fieldName + '.$error.required">Lūdzu aizpildiet šo lauku</div>';
                    }

                    html = '<div><ng-form name="eavform">' + html + element.html() + '</ng-form></div>';

                    var newElem = angular.element(html);

                    var attrElem = input ? newElem.find(input) : newElem;

                    attrElem.attr('ng-model', 'vals.eav.' + config.ID);
                    attrElem.addClass('form-control');
                    attrElem.attr('placeholder', config.description);
                    attrElem.attr('name', fieldName);

                    if (config.isRequired) {
                        attrElem.attr('ng-required', true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Fields from inspect element from browser:

```
<div class="form-group field_eav field_eav_2 field_eav_epasts" config="{&quot;ID&quot;:2,&quot;eavFieldGroupID&quot;:null,&quot;classID&quot;:2,&quot;stringIdentifier&quot;:null,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;E-pasts&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:&quot;E-PASTS *&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:3,&quot;dataType&quot;:1,&quot;position&quot;:1,&quot;handle&quot;:&quot;epasts&quot;,&quot;isMultiValue&quot;:null,&quot;isRequired&quot;:1,&quot;isDisplayed&quot;:null,&quot;isDisplayedInList&quot;:null,&quot;valuePrefix&quot;:null,&quot;valueSuffix&quot;:null,&quot;valueFieldID&quot;:null,&quot;fieldName&quot;:&quot;specField_2&quot;}">
    <label class="control-label ng-binding">E-pasts</label>
    <div ng-transclude="">
        <div class="ng-scope">
            <ng-form name="eavform" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                <input type="text" ng-model="vals.eav.2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" placeholder="E-PASTS *" name="eav_2" ng-required="true" required="required">
                <div class="text-danger ng-hide" ng-show="isSubmitted &amp;&amp; eavform.eav_2.$error.required">Lūdzu aizpildiet šo lauku</div>
            </ng-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-transclude="">
    <div class="ng-scope">
        <ng-form name="eavform" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vals.eav.2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" placeholder="E-PASTS *" name="eav_2" ng-required="true" required="required">
            <div class="text-danger ng-hide" ng-show="isSubmitted &amp;&amp; eavform.eav_2.$error.required">Lūdzu aizpildiet šo lauku</div>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code from the file

```
    <eav-formatted config="[[ eavFieldsHandle.epasts.toJson() ]]">
        <eav-field></eav-field>
    </eav-formatted>

            <legend style="padding-top: 0px;">Izvēlieties piegādes veidu: </legend>
              <input type="radio" class="input" name="radio-1" id="radio-1" value="Option1">
              <span><b>Choose 1</span>
              <input type="radio" class="input" name="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="Option2">
            <span><b>Choose 2</span>
```

Script of the file

```
      $( function() {

    $('input[name="radio-1"]').on('change', function() {

        $('input[name="eav_2"]').val($(this).val());
    });
} );
```

Comment: You dont need to specify double quotes on name attribute. It should be name=radio-1

Comment: You can try with click event on radio button instead of change event.

Comment: Tried with click event either. `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="radio-1"]').click(function(){
        $('input[name="eav_2"]').val("Option1");
    });
});` Noticed i can't even get initial value from text field. value="Option1" It is just not displaying it.

Comment: Just updated my code with fields creator. Noticed if i remove from `ng-model` from `attrElem.attr('ng-model', 'vals.eav.' + config.ID);` then value is showed but i can't submit  SUBMIT the form.